# Switch between OSMC and Chromium kiosk

Tags: chromium, osmc, kiosk

I like OSMC, but wanted to be able to switch between it and Chromium in kiosk mode on the fly (something like FullPageOS).

My use case is I’d like to write a web app running on a desktop machine on my home LAN which the Pi kiosk browser will be set to show. The app will be a chore/homework tracker for my kids. The app will store whether or not they’ve earned screen time. When they have, I’d like the Pi to switch to OSMC (or something else that’ll run Plex and/or Netflix) for a given amount of time.

I know the use case is complex and not a good scope for a question here, so my actual question at this point is, is there a way to present two applications, switching between them based on software I can control on a timer?

I’m not opposed to a multi-Pi solution. One idea would be a Zero that does the control and does something simple like switching between two HDMI inputs, one from a Pi running the browser kiosk, and the other running OSMC.

Comment: how about create bash or command script using [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)

Comment: @adadion: OSMC doesn't use X so I don't that can work

Comment: `One idea would be a Zero that does the control and does something simple like switching between two HDMI inputs`. Not sure if that's actually simple. Maybe use a HDMI Switch. There are remotely controlled ones and it may be possible to remotely control them from a Zero.

Comment: @Dirk ah, then Kodi is the alternative, Plex and Netflix addon are available

Comment: @adadion: yes, wirh Kodi + Chromium on Raspbian it could work.

Comment: @Dirk hm, and `One idea would be a Zero that does the control and does something simple like switching between two HDMI inputs`, [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/switching-between-tvs-displaying-osmc-on-raspberry-pi-through-mobile-apllicatio?rq=1) will be do trick, but lot of effort to be done